# jQuery datepicker does not work after Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datepicker

Hello I try these code i am  try and try but code are not running successfully in my code section  how can i resolve this error.

**This is my datepicker code**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {

    $("#departure_date").datepicker();
  });
</script>
```

**This is my ajax call function**

```
function CheckUnique(mobile) {
  //alert(mobile);
  var xmlhttp;
  if (mobile == "") {
    // document.getElementById(r_number).innerHTML="";
    alert("Mobile Number is Blank!!");
    document.getElementById('mobile').focus();
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("error_message").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
      //alert();
      if (xmlhttp.responseText != '') {
        document.getElementById('button').style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax.php?mobile=" + mobile, true);
  $("#arrival_date").datepicker();

  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**That's data are coming from ajax**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-lg-4 ">
    <label for="pwd">Departure Date:</label>
    <input type="text" name="departure_date" class="form-control" id="departure_date" placeholder="11/12/2015">
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is your ajax call replacing or adding `departure_date`?

Comment: Try to put $("#arrival_date").datepicker(); in your onreadystatechange function. Just a question, if you are including jQuery, why don't you just use [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) instead of all the xmlhttp stuff?

Comment: since you are already using jQuery, why not refactor your ajax call to use $.ajax or the http method helpers? It will give you error handling and browser compatibility plus readability without costing you much.

Comment: @heavyhorse $ajax code are not working on the onchage event if any code this related then please send me as a answer for my better

Comment: Not enough code to tell (where is your code assigning CheckUnique to some form event) - but I'm gonna guess you are not using preventDefault to stop the form from submitting once the Ajax triggers.

Comment: @James This is my code CheckUnique 

<input type="number" name="mobile" class="form-control" id="mobile" onchange="return CheckUnique(this.value);" required>

where